# Can you run Ubuntu MAAS without a BMC Card?

Tags: networking, juju, maas

I'm trying to setup Ubuntu MAAS on a three node network. All computers are off-the-shelf computers. The official documentation from Ubuntu states that it needs a BMC card to be able to power cycle the machine and will not deploy the machine otherwise. My question is without a BMC is there still a way to use Ubuntu MAAS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Boot the PC via PXE, Commissioning should start and soon you should see it appear in the "Machines" list.  You can edit the machine then go to **Configuration** --> **Power Type** and select "Manual".

Then it goes without saying that without a BMC you will obviously have to trigger startup/shutdown/reboots manually.  So from here on out you will have to trigger the Commissioning/Deploy of the machine and then manually boot the PC.